# How can I import ares.h file on mosquitto protocol?

Tags: mosquitto, srv

I've implemented mosquitto on my ARM target board.

I added `-DWITH_SRV` in Makefile, because I need to add `SRV Loopup` function on my system.

But it returns error

> fatal error: ares.h: No such file or directory

I have no idea how can I fix it.

1. Just add `ares.h` file in /include folder? If then, loop up feature will be work normally?
2. Should install ares library on my system?

Could anyone answer about my question?

Answer (score 6):

You need to have the c-ares library installed in your system. It should be pretty straightforward to install the `libc-ares-dev` package using your Linux distro package manager.

Alternatively, and for other operating sytems, you can get the library from its official [website](http://c-ares.haxx.se/).

Answer (score 0):

On Suse install libcares-devel.